# Rest api end point for get the schema list for given catalog_id /catalog_name

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog, databricks-rest-api

can you please confirm on end point URL to get the  list of schemes for given catalog_id or catalog_name in Unity catalog stand When I tried use below end point getting 404 .

```
endpoint = f"{workspace_url}/api/2.1/unity-catalogs/{catalog_name}/schemas"
```

Reference : [link](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/schemas/list)

tried both

```
endpoint = f"{workspace_url}/api/2.1/unity-catalogs/schemas"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really it's best to use Databricks Python SDK for that: https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sdk/ - it even supports "transparent" authentication when code is executed in the notebook

Answer (score 0):

found the answer and end point should be

```
endpoint = f"{workspace_url}/api/2.1/unity-catalog/schemas?catalog_name=<catalog-name>"
```